# Exact xpath query to scrape value from dynamic webpage

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

I'm searching the xpath query to scrape the "algo score" from [this webpage](https://coincheckup.com/coins/cardano/analysis). The algo score is highlighted with a red border in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqoOM.png).

I've tried several Xpath queries without results such as:

```
//*[@id="content"]/main/section/div/div/header/div[7]/span[2]/a/text()

//a[@class="no-und label label-ghost text-sm"]//text()

//div[@ng-if="::details.total_score"]/a/text()
```

Comment: Is it saved directly in the `DOM` tree?

Comment: no, i think you are right. These elements are dynamically added. Is there a way to scrape them?

Comment: Sure, try using selenium.

Comment: Another approach `//*[@class='primary']/a[contains(@class,'text-sm')]`.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at Selenium. The query you suggested gives me 0 respons. Does it work on your side?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
string(.//a[@href = '/coins/cardano/analysis'])
```